# collective.documentviewer with plone 4.2.1 throws up errors

Tags: python, linux, plone

I uploaded files into the plone site after installing the collective.documentviewer without any problem. I was able to preview the files correctly for sometime using the document viewer but after sometime when I restarted the server and tried accessing the folder contailing the pdf and doc files, it throws out some traceback as follows:

> ```
> URL: /abc/demo/ofs.interfaces.ifolder-dvpdf-group-view
> Line 24, Column 0
> Expression: <PythonExpr view.results(portal_type=file_types)>
> Names:
> {'container': <ATFolder at /abc/demo>,
>  'context': <ATFolder at /abc/demo>,
>  'default': <object object at 0xb75ec7e0>,
>  'here': <ATFolder at /abc/demo>,
>  'loop': {},
>  'nothing': None,
>  'options': {'args': ()},
>  'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xcb2eaf4>,
>  'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://88.198.104.37:8081/abc/demo/dvpdf-group-view>,
>  'root': <Application at >,
>  'template': <TTWViewTemplate at /abc/demo/ofs.interfaces.ifolder-dvpdf-group-view>,
>  'user': <PloneUser 'xyz'>,
>  'view': <five.customerize.zpt.TTWView object at 0xc80df8c>}
> Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
> __traceback_info__: view.results(portal_type=file_types)
> Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
> Module collective.documentviewer.views, line 613, in results
> Module collective.documentviewer.views, line 604, in getContents
> Module collective.documentviewer.views, line 630, in b_size
> AttributeError: 'TTWView' object has no attribute 'global_settings'
> ```

I am unable to view the folder contents. Goes without saying that I cannot view the file with the viewer. I have tried deactivating and reactivating the documentviewer and also created a new plone instance. But face the same problem after some time. Can anyone guide please?

Comment: Is there a customization in portal_view_customizations? go to http://yoursite/portal_view_customizations/manage_main

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1716549/mat there is no customization for views done so far except I cahnged the plone.footer message body and have overridden the at_download code by replaceing it with no code(blank), so that it does not download the file when its hlink is clicked.

Comment: Which version of collective.documentviewer do you have installed? the line 630 in the master has nothing to do with b_size.  https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/blob/master/collective/documentviewer/views.py#L630 Try a newer version or from source

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1716549/mat I use buildout.cfg: eggs and zcml to add this product collective.documentviewer. Version of document viewer installed is 2.2.1, Plone 4.2.1.1 (4207)
CMF 2.2.6, Zope 2.13.16, Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 16 2013, 12:18:07) [GCC 4.7.2]
PIL 1.7.7 (Pillow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Plone 4.1.4 version and it turns out to be more stable with this add-on. It did not give me any errors. Also noticed if you even try to customize the view i.e /home/plone/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2.1-py2.6.egg/collective/documentviewer/templates/documentviewer.pt, it throws up some error for 'widget', even without changing anything there